# SQL Server : Insert into 2 tables from a select with one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

From a select, I try to insert data into two tables :

```
DECLARE @ORIGIN TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50), STREET VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @PERSON TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @ADDRESS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, ID_PERSON INT, STREET VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @ORIGIN 
VALUES ('Carl', 'MAX', '1 All Road'),
       ('Elsa', 'SCARLET', 'On the tail')
```

I want something like :

```
INSERT INTO @PERSON (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, o.STREET INTO @ADDRESS (ID_PERSON, STREET)
    SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME 
    FROM @ORIGIN AS o
```

The OUTPUT doesn't have the same columns as the `SELECT`:

> The multi-part identifier "o.STREET" could not be bound.

Comment: Your fields don't align; the `o.STREET` is not part of the `SELECT` statement and should be `inserted.STREET` if it were included. Also `@PERSON` does not contain the field `STREET`

Comment: Why does it have to be a single query?  If I had this task, I'd do it with a stored procedure.

Comment: @Perter : Of course, but if I can't add STREET in the SELECT because STREET isn't in '@PERSON' table. I need transfert STREET from '@ORIGIN' directly in '@ADDRESS'.

Comment: @Brian : For the beauty. Actualy, I have made a stored procedure to continue my work.

Comment: And you will need to do that as a separate `INSERT` statement; you can;t do it like this.

Comment: @Perter : The second INSERT ('@ADDRESS') don't know the id generate in first insert ('@PERSON'). But if you can, two inserts is a valid answer.

Comment: @marc_s : Of course, but I hope it has a trick.

Comment: Sorry, @marc_s, but you are wrong on this one. There is a trick - see dupe for details.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: interesting - thanks for the link - I wasn't aware of that approach; you learn something new every day!

Comment: @ZoharPeled: The merge solution is short and fast, perfect. For 200k Rows, 6 minutes with cursor and 20 secondes with merge. Thank.

Comment: Glad to help ;-)